# Xcode Simulator showing black screen after app launces

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Today, while working on an app, I went to run the simulator and instead of seeing the normal progression, I see only a blank grey screen.  I never see the usual apple loading screen, the home screen, or my app launch.  However, I know that the app is launching because print statements in my ViewDidLoad all print.  Additionally, if I click in the area where buttons are, they run their functions.

I know that the problem is not a bug in the app, because I went back and ran old apps I have developed in the past and they also show only the grey screen.

I tried resetting content and settings on the simulator, but that did not help.  I also played around with the scale of the simulator, but that didn't help either.  I tried on the iPhone 5, 6, 6 plus, and others and they all have the same issue.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an external monitor, try unplugging it, restarting the simulator, and plugging the monitor back in.  Worked for me.

Comment: I did have an external monitor, that I also noticed was acting buggy later, so they are definitely related.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened, but restarting my computer seems to have solved the issue.